# SignalR and Hibernate

Tags: nhibernate, signalr

I am using SignalR 2.0 for live chat and notifications and also using NHibernate (with FluentNHibernate) for persistence.

I am building single page app and all calls are done using XHR and WebSocket with SignalR .

Problem is: Everything written into database through SignalR is not recognized by nhibernate session.

When I do full page refresh changes are there so I suppose it is about SignalR 2.0 contains no HttpContext that we are using when building NHibernate SessionFactory.